# SSRS Parameters Hidden and Unhidden

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2016

I have a report that requires a branch name as parameter. There are also other parameters like business year, quarter etc.

This report will be accessed via two methods.

**1. Via the SQL Server Reporting Portal.**

Users at head office will access this report via the Report Server Portal and be able to pick the parameter value seeing as they are allowed to see all the branches data.

User can change the Branch

[image: User can change the Branch]

**2. Via software**

Calling a URL inside the software used by branches, the value of the parameter will be set in the URL based on the branch accessing it and locked so the users can change it another branch.

User can not change the Branch

[image: User can not change the Branch]

How can I create the parameter in such a way that it is conditionally locked? Can the fact that it is locked be specified in the URL that the software calls?

I really want to avoid creating two different reports for Branch and Head Office.

Comment: I think you should be able to do this by restricting the "Available Values" for the branch name parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have found a workaround (well actually a better approach).

*Credit goes to Kidiskidvogingogin*

By using the UserID built-in parameter, I can limit user on the what data is displayed in the drop down box for Branch Name. A user linked to branch, will only see that branch, the user linked to headoffice, will see ALL branches.

By filling the parameter with a dataset, I can filter the data set to only return branches applicable to that user.